# use of iterators from the middle of the loop

Tags: c++, iterator

i have a vector of vector "mydata". i want to iterate my data in negative direction. the iterator should be started from the middle to the beginning.
i wish to use following way;

```
vector<vector<int> >::const_iterator points;
int i, k;

(lets assume k = 10)

for (i=k, points=mydata.begin()+k; i != -1; i--, points--){

     //do stuff
}
```

does this way is the proper way to iterate in backward? (I am using dev c++, so predicates and some modern commands cant be used.)
Hope your suggestions to do this.

Comment: You should really really really upgrade to an up-to-date IDE and compiler. Dev-C++ was junk 5 years ago when it was last maintained. Today, it is *obsolete* junk.

Comment: @jalf: ok. thanks.  any free version plz.

Comment: Which OS? On Windows, you might want to take a look at MS Visual C++ Express. If you want a cross-platform IDE, there's Code::Blocks or Eclipse or a handful of others. Take your pick, or just use Google.

Comment: @jalf: yes. windows xp. thanks

Comment: @jalf: You're half right - Dev-C++ *is* junk, but it is being [maintained once more](http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's vector, you dont need to use iterator at all:

```
for (int k = 4; k >= 0; k--)
{
    // do something with v[k]
}
```

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 };
    vector<int> v(arr, arr + 10);

    for (int k = 4; k >= 0; k--)
    {
        cout << v[k] << endl;
    }
}
```

output:

```
5
4
3
2
1
```

Comment: [not my downvote] `i` is redundant, as you can just use `v[k]` instead of `*(i+k)`. The question is about using iterators, but you use an index.

Comment: @MSalters: Good note. He wanted to know how to iterate through vector backwards I guess.

Answer (score 4):

A possible solution using `reverse_iterator`s [`vector::rbegin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/rbegin) and [`vector::rend()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/rend):

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector> 

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        v.push_back(i);
    }

    for (std::vector<int>::const_reverse_iterator it = v.rbegin()+(v.size()/2);
         it != v.rend();
         it++)
    {
        std::cout << *it << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use std::vector::const_reverse_iterator. Here's the example of how to iterate backwards through the vector, starting from the middle:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;

    for(int i = 0; i< 10; i++)
        v.push_back(i);

    std::vector<int>::const_reverse_iterator it = v.rbegin() + 5;


    for(;it != v.rend(); it++)
    {
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
4 
3 
2 
1 
0
```

Answer (score 0):

There are roughly two nice solutions. Either you just write the loop:

```
vector<int>::const_iterator i = v.begin() + 4;
do {
  // stuff with *i
while (--i != v.begin());
```

or use reverse iterators and the standard STL algorithms:

```
std::for_each(v.rend()-4, v.rend(), &stuff);
```